# Setting audio tag currentTime in Opera & Firefox causes an error

Tags: html, firefox, cross-browser, opera, html5-audio

I have an html5 audio tag in my webpage:

```
<div id="audioContainer">
<audio id="siteAudio" src="http://myDomain.com/audio/soundFx.mp3" type="audio/flac"   preloading="auto" audio="true"></audio>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to play the sound from a different starting point every time the user presses a different button on my site. Creating sound fx for clicks.
 
I’m using the following JS code to do this:
    var m_currentAudioElement = document.getElementById(‘siteAudio’);
    m_currentAudioElement.currentTime = 1.00; /* or 2.00, 3.00*/
    m_currentAudioElement.play();
This works fine on Chrome, Safari and IE (surprisingly).
But when executed in Opera and Firefox I get the following error on the setting currentTime command: “Unhandled DOMException: INVALID_STATE_ERR” 
Any ideas why this is happening? Or how to overcome this?

Thanks a lot,
Moshe S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's breaking because mp3 audio files are [not supported in Firefox and Opera:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats)

You'll need to create an ogg version of your audio and use multiple `<source>` elements inside your `<audio>`. There's an example (albeit for video, not audio) on the page linked above.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I add the two sources: mp3 & ogg, and the audio is working on all browsers.
FYI: I also tested this solution on mobile:  Android & IPhone 4S and the solution also works. cool:)